# Http-Post edit action calling ISession.SaveOrUpdate(obj) creates new entity

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm creating an Asp.Net MVC 3 application with NHibernate as my ORM. In my my edit action method I call the Save method in my DatabaseAccessObject class, but instead of updating the object it creates a new one. I can't figure out why.

Here's the code for the method that returns my configured SessionFactory, and my global.asax.cs file where I'm storing the SessionFactory:

```
public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
        {
            return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString("Server=(local);Database=WebApplicationPbiBoard;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<WebApplicationPbiBoard.Models.ScrumModels_Mappings.PbiMap>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true))
                .CurrentSessionContext("web")
                .BuildSessionFactory();
        }

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; private set; }
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //my additions
        SessionFactory = NHibernateConfigurator.CreateSessionFactory();
    }

    protected void Application_OnEnd()
    {
        SessionFactory.Dispose();
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();

        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
    }

    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory);
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant snippet from my DataAccessObject, which simply wraps NHibernate CRUD operations:

```
public class DatabaseAccessObject<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly ISession session = MvcApplication.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        private ISession Session { get { return session; } }

        public T Save(T obj)
        {
            ITransaction transaction = null;
            try
            {
                transaction = Session.BeginTransaction();

                Session.SaveOrUpdate(obj);
                transaction.Commit();
                return obj;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (transaction != null && transaction.IsActive)
                    transaction.Rollback();

                throw;
            }
        }
```

And finally, here's the code for my Http-Post edit method:

```
private readonly DatabaseAccessObject<Sprint> db = new DatabaseAccessObject<Sprint>();
private DatabaseAccessObject<Sprint> Db { get { return db; } }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Sprint editedSprint)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Db.Save(editedSprint);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
        return View(editedSprint);            
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you're saving probably hasn't got the Id set on it.

SaveOrUpdate does one of two things:
- Update() if the Id is set.
- Save() if the Id is not set.

refer to the docs: 
http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html

Comment: That was it exactly. The Id of every Sprint was set to zero. But I can't figure out why that would be the case. I though NHibernate was supposed to handle assigning the Id by default.

Comment: Yup it does. Your bug is somewhere else.